# Installing the Browser Compatibility Files in solution without Visual Studio

Tags: asp.net, visual-studio, nuget-package

I have designed some pages . I hosted in the server (The machine which is specially  for hosting purpose) .In that Server There is no visual Studio .
Here I am facing one problem .in local I have installed IE11 and FF5> browser capabilities through the Nuget Library package manager . I need to to install the same package in server machine .How to install the packages without visual studio ?

Comment: have you tried nuget command line?

Comment: I have tried . I don't Know whether i did correctly or not . Can you send me a correct link to achieve that

Comment: In Server machine I don't have the Visual studio .